# Unity Custom Editor Raycast Not Working Right After When Instantiate Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, editor, raycasting

1. I created Test.cs and TestEditor.cs (Test class is a simple class.)
2. Test.cs is empty and here is TestEditor.cs:

> ```
> using UnityEngine;
> using UnityEditor;
>
> [CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
> public class TestEditor : Editor
> {
>     Test test;
>     GameObject cube;
>     GameObject sphere;
>
>     public override void OnInspectorGUI()
>     {
>         base.OnInspectorGUI();
>
>         test = (Test)target;
>
>         if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
>         {
>             Create();
>             RayCastTest();
>         }
>
>         if (GUILayout.Button("RayCast Test"))
>         {
>             RayCastTest();
>         }
>     }
>
>     void Create()
>     {
>         cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
>         cube.transform.position = test.transform.position;
>         sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
>         sphere.transform.position = test.transform.position + Vector3.right * 5f;
>     }
>
>     void RayCastTest()
>     {
>         Ray ray;
>         RaycastHit hit;
>         ray = new Ray(test.transform.position, Vector3.right);
>         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000f))
>         {
>             GameObject target = hit.collider.gameObject;
>             target.transform.localScale *= 2f;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. If I press the "Create" button in Unity, the objects are created but the RayCastTest() function does not work. But, if I press the "Create" button first and then the "RayCast Test" button, the function works.

So, How can I get the RayCastTest() function to work in the first part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raycast is from the `Physics` engine. Afaik it only works after one `Physics` update since before that the `Collider` might not be recalculated yet ->The `Physics` doesn't "know" that `Collider` yet.

You could try and force it using [`Physics.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html) after your `Create`

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
{
    Create();
    Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    RayCastTest();
}
```

---

Additionally you **might** have to disable the [`Physics.autoSimulation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-autoSimulation.html) .. unfortunately the API isn't so clear on that. If it is the case you might do it like

```
     Physics.autoSimulation = false;
     Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
     Physics.autoSimulation = true;
```

---

Also [`Physics.SyncTransforms`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SyncTransforms.html) might help

> When a `Transform` component changes, any `Rigidbody` or `Collider` on that `Transform` or its children may need to be repositioned, rotated or scaled depending on the change to the `Transform`. Use this function to flush those changes to the `Physics` engine manually.

Since you are moving your created objects you might additionally have to call this (again **might** be necessary to be used together with [`Physics.autoSyncTransforms`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-autoSyncTransforms.html)) before the simulation like

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
{
    Create();
    
    Physics.SyncTransforms();

    Physics.autoSimulation = false;
    Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    Physics.autoSimulation = true;

    RayCastTest();
}
```

Comment: Good explanation.. Thanks.